# regex how i write this pattern?

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

```
$string = "anyWord Hello A 1 *** .";
preg_match('/(.*?) Hello (A|B) (1|0) (if(g2 == B)then|else).*/i',$string,$match);
//             g1          g2    g3   -->|            
print_r($match);
```

ٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍ
What i do ?

Comment: What is `(?(3))`? What do you think it is doing?

Comment: i think get value of group 3 and in condition check this value

Comment: To my knowledge, that is not a feature of *any* flavour of regex and I have no idea where you might have gotten this concept from...

Comment: pls example for me. my english is slow.

Comment: Where did you learn about `(?(3))`?

Comment: Accidental ! _________________

Comment: overall i want use a value of a group in my condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/(.*?) Hello ([AB]) (?|(0)|(1) (\*\*\*))/i",$string,$match);
```

The `(?|...|...)` structure allows subpatterns in the alternation to be numbered independently of each other. Otherwise, you'd end up with match `3` either being `0` or nothing, and match `4/5` being `1/***` or nothing. The structure combined them, to get match `3` being `0` or `1`, and match `4` being nothing or `***`

Comment: ... Then what is your problem? In what way does my answer fail to solve it?

Comment: overall i want use a value of a group in my condition

Comment: ... What group? You know what, forget it. I'm done here. I'm not in the mood to crush you until you finally give the information I need. I'm not a gestapo officer.

Comment: You mean what you get in `$match[1]`?

Comment: yes but in regex and use in regex in condition =>(?($match[1] ==1)then|else)